# Is there a way to convert a Meteor JS project to a project which can be used in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, meteor

Business strikes again - and we need to make a new website. I'm not sure how to pull this off, but basically , I need to make a MeteorJS project which can talk to a c# backend. We all know that ASP.NET and MeteorJS is two different platforms, but seems my company wants to use both methodologies at the same time.

So as I asked in the title, is it possible to create a MeteorJS project, add it as a project to visual studio, and have it talk to an ASP.NET backend? If so - what are the steps I need to take in order to accomplish this?

Comment: NuGet Package manager didn't come to the rescue either - doesn't seem to be "Meteor" projects

Comment: The Meteor folks are working on something they call [Apllo](http://www.apollostack.com/). That might be something for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your C# project can expose a number of REST interfaces then Meteor can easily consume those and be "just a front-end". You won't get reactivity unless you use Apollo for your data access layer.

Comment: I have thought about doing it this way - having the c# project standalone exposing it's method  through a REST interface and seperately hosted, and Meteor being hosted standalone to consume that interface

However, I never heard of Apollo. do you have any credible tutorials I cann look at for this ?

Comment: https://medium.com/apollo-stack/tutorial-building-a-graphql-server-cddaa023c035#.9ljkiw657